# (Unity3D) When the Camera is in a object, Camera will stop rendering the object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 2018.4.14f1 personal (I don't use 2019 or 2020 because it lags my computer)

I'm using the Unity Standard Assets Player Prefab and Cinemachine Freelook for the camera. I have some water, and when my player walks into it, its fine. However, when the camera comes into the water, it stops rendering the water. Is there anyway I can fix it?

Update: I've somewhat got it working, however its hollow when your inside. Is there anyway to fix that?

Video : https://easyupload.io/2b0p3a

(I'm quite a noob so if you need any screenshots please ask.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you attach screenshots of the issue along with screenshots of the Inspector window for the Camera we can better help you.

Comment: What you're describing seems to be a matter of backface culling, and is not specific to Unity3D. Note that a CGI model is just a collection of triangles: when your computer renders the model, it's just drawing a lot of different triangles. However, to save computational power, these triangles are (usually) only visible from one side. This is why, when you zoom inside your character in a game, you don't usually see his head from the inside. There are a few different workarounds depending on what you want specifically; try to search around, or add more details about your setup and goal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the water will only rendered when looking from the outside as the normalized are modeled so. The program renders outs objects that it thinks is not in view. You can load the model into a 3d program and then copy and invert the model to allow your camera to see the water, or I believe there are some [shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) option to stop this optimization. You can also look in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/ez7kdd/if_you_put_camera_inside_3d_cube_it_wont_see_it/).